# How do I print a string in one line in MARIE?

Tags: marie

I want to print a set of letters in one line in MARIE. I modified the code to print `Hello World` and came up with:

```
    ORG     0       / implemented using "do while" loop
WHILE,      LOAD        STR_BASE    / load str_base into ac
    ADD     ITR         / add index to str_base
    STORE       INDEX       / store (str_base + index) into ac
    CLEAR               / set ac to zero
    ADDI        INDEX       / get the value at ADDR
    SKIPCOND    400     / SKIP if ADDR = 0 (or null char)
    JUMP        DO      / jump to DO
    JUMP        PRINT       / JUMP to END

DO, STORE       TEMP                / output value at ADDR
    LOAD        ITR         / load iterator into ac
    ADD         ONE         / increment iterator by one
    STORE       ITR         / store ac in iterator
    JUMP        WHILE       / jump to while

PRINT,      SUBT    ONE
            SKIPCOND  000
            JUMP     PR
            HALT

PR,     OUTPUT
        JUMP WHILE

ONE,        DEC     1
ITR,        DEC     0
INDEX,      HEX     0
STR_BASE,   HEX     12      / memory location of str
STR,        HEX     48      / H
    HEX     65      / E
    HEX     6C      / L
    HEX     6C      / L
    HEX     6F      / O
    HEX     0       / carriage return
    HEX     57      / W
    HEX     6F      / O
    HEX     72      / R
    HEX     6C      / L
    HEX     64      / D
    HEX     0       / NULL char
```

My program ends up halting past two iterations. I can't seem to figure out how to print a set of characters in one line. Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Your value of STR_BASE is almost certainly incorrect. Based on what is here I would say it needs to be 18 instead of 12. Also you would either want to remove current null char that is between "HELLO" and "WORLD" and replace it with a space or simply remove that line, depending on your intended output.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code which was tested on [Marie.js](https://marie.js.org/):

1. `STR_BASE` stores the incorrect HEX value.
2. `ORG 0`.
3. Null char character and carriage return have the same hex value. This will cause your loop to stop after encountering the first null value.
4. Your PRINT is not printing anything. Output is the correct keyword to print a character.

### Calculating address of `STR`

1. Ignoring all empty lines and comment-only lines, start counting from 1 and find the line number of the `STR` label.
2. Subtract 1 from the line number and convert the result to HEX.
3. Therefore, the address of the `STR` label in your code is `18`. Thus `18` should be stored at `STR_BASE`.

## Amended code

The comments are self-explanatory. The value stored at `STR_BASE`  for my code is  `16` (instead of `18` because my code has less instructions).

```
ORG 000 

WHILE,      LOAD        STR_BASE    
            ADD         ITR         
            STORE       INDEX       / index = str_base + itr
            LOADI       INDEX       / get the value at INDEX
            SKIPCOND    400         / check value at INDEX
            JUMP        DO          / else restart loop
            HALT                    / if null char, end program

DO,     Output                  / output value at ADDR
        LOAD        ITR        
        ADD         ONE         
        STORE       ITR         / itr += 1
        JUMP        WHILE       / jump to while

        
ONE,        DEC     1
ITR,        DEC     0
INDEX,      HEX     0
STR_BASE,   HEX     10      / memory location of str
STR,        HEX     48      / H
            HEX     65      / E
            HEX     6C      / L
            HEX     6C      / L
            HEX     6F      / O
            HEX     20      / space
            HEX     57      / W
            HEX     6F      / O
            HEX     72      / R
            HEX     6C      / L
            HEX     64      / D
            HEX     0       / NULL char
```

On [Marie.js](https://marie.js.org/) with output mode set to `Unicode`, the output is `Hello World`.

You can use [this site](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0020/index.htm) to find the HEX values of various Unicode characters.